# Is there a Gebish way of selecting elements between two elements?

Tags: geb

I'm trying to write a Geb Module that gets all div elements between two elements and can't see a nice way of doing that.

I can probably do some sort of groovy list manipulation or iterative method but thought I'd check first to see if I am missing a Gebish way.

The html is roughly structured like this

```
<div id="theParent">
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">
        <div id="sectionHeader">Header 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">
        <div id="anotherSectionHeader">Header 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">
        <div id="yetAnotherSectionHeader">Header 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-gridlayout-slot">
        <div id="actionButton"></div>
</div>
```

The content section of my module looks like

```
static content = {
    headerOne { $("#sectionHeader")}
    headerTwo { $("#anotherSectionHeader")}
    headerThree { $("#yetAnotherSectionHeader")}
    ...
}
```

I was hoping there is a Gebish way of collecting all `$("div.v-gridlayout-slot")` that are between headerOne and headerTwo but can't see anything appropriate.

Solution from erdi:

```
    Navigator getElementsBetween(def fromElement, def toElement) {
        String nextId = toElement.attr('id')
        def betweenElements = fromElement.parent().nextAll("div.v-gridlayout-slot").takeWhile {
            !it.has(id: nextId)
        }
        $(*betweenElements)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, according to the html structure you posted you are not looking for `$("div.v-gridlayout-slot")` that are between `headerOne` and `headerTwo` but are between the parrents of `headerOne` and `headerTwo`. I'd write it this way:

```
def nextHeaderId = headerTwo.attr('id')
def betweenHeaders = headerOne.parent.nextAll("div.v-gridlayout-slot").takeWhile { it.hasNot(id: nextHeaderId) }
```

`betweenHeaders` will end up being a `Collection<Navigator>` (because of use of `until` which is a default Groovy method on `Iterable` with `Navigator` being `Iterable<Navigator>` and not a method on `Navigator`) so if you need to turn it into a navigator you'll have to call `sum()` on it:

```
betweenHeaders.sum()
```

or spread it and pass it to `$()`:

```
$(*betweenHeaders)
```

Comment: Thanks for this erdi.  I couldn't get it to work quite like that.  There doesn't seem to an until method?  I got it working using this though. betweenHeaders = fromHeader.parent().nextAll("div.v-gridlayout-slot").takeWhile { !it.has(id: nextHeaderId)}  Thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. You correctly figured out that I meant to use `takeWhile()` and not `until()` which I seem to simply have made up... I will update the answer.